# defining local variables using an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

May be a silly question, but just wanted to know if there's any difference (performance wise) between the following.

```
SomeObject.prototype.myFunc = function() {
 var a = 123;
 var b = "something";
 ...
}   

SomeObject.prototype.myFunc = function() {
 var loc = {};
 loc.a = 123;
 loc.b = "something";
 ...
}
```

I've been doing the second way, just so its been easier to debug by doing console.log(loc) and it's also a habit from doing server side code where I've been defining local structures.

Comment: Use a profiler and find out. I doubt there'd be any noticeable difference

Comment: Ya, dude, you are talking about the era of 2.6GHZ computers with multi cores and 6 or 8 GB of RAM.....

Comment: Here, I did it for you ~ http://jsperf.com/direct-variable-vs-object-property-assignment

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about micro-optimisation

Comment: Turns out I was very wrong about there being no noticeable difference :)

Comment: If you debug using a debugger instead of `console.log`, you will be able to inspect scopes just as you currently do with objects. No reason to use objects here.

Comment: geez thanks Phil I thought it would be slight difference but that's huge. Since I'm looping over the DOM 100s of times in some instances I need to make sure any functions being called don't cause any bottlenecks either and this seems like a good one that I need to stamp out!

Answer (score 0):

As per the tests done by Phil (http://jsperf.com/direct-variable-vs-object-property-assignment) there's a noticeable difference between using direct variable assignment and object property assignment.

Definitely will be using **direct variable assignment**

Answer (score 0):

Technically, objects cost without a doubt, because object has much complicated data structure than primitive types.

Practically, better readability and maintainability are important as well. Unless your code is running on server side with Node.js, it's not likely that your code would run millions times like that, so the performance issue on this point isn't really noticeable or becomes bottle neck.